# Using ADFS, SAMLResponse is not sent to ACS URL appearing in SAMLRequest [authnRequest]

Tags: single-sign-on

I had initially the same issue when using pingFederate server, that time I used acsIdx attribute as querystring in the idpInit SSO end point and my problem was solved.

I wanted to ask is there similar attribute in ADFS too, which when set will send the saml response to the desired ACS URL instead of the default.

Also, I wanted to know that if I set the assertionConsumerURL in the samlRequest will the ADFS be able to send the response to that URL, even if the authnRequest is not signed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it is possible to have ADFS (RP-STS) include a different ACS URL or ACSIndex in the AuthnRequest. In playing with ADFS, I've never seen that this type of modification was possible.

It seems possible to have ADFS (as the IP-STS) send an Assertion to more than 1 ACS URL based upon the ACS URL or ACS Index in the AuthnRequest as long as they are listed in the Relaying Party Trust Endpoints list. However, per the spec, if the ACS URL is NOT listed and the SP is NOT signing the AuthnRequest, then ADFS should reject the AuthnRequest as non-compliant.

HTH - Ian